# How to create a simple neural network with tensorflowjs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to create a simple nn with tensorflowjs.
Training data is:

```
INPUT:
[
  {
    param1: 0,
    param2: 0.034,
    param3: 0.147,
    param4: 1,
    param5: 0,
    param6: 0.028,
  }
]
OUTPUT:
0.035
```

Where I can find a simple example?

Comment: You can look into the official guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put more clarification to what you are trying to do.

Firstly, you need to tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve (i.e *a model that takes x as input and predict y as an output*), this way it is easy to suggest the right solution/ model/ approach (e.g linear regression, binary classification, multiclass classification etc).

**For example:** here is a simple model trying to predict or determine the download time [secs] for any file size [MB].

P.S: Note that this is to show you how a simple model might look like and not comprehensive enough (this particular example needs more improvement).

```js
// Data set for the training
// Dataset obtained from https://codepen.io/tfjs-book/pen/dgQVze
const trainData = {
  sizeMB:  [9.000, 0.001, 0.100, 5.000, 0.100, 8.000, 6.000, 0.050, 0.500, 0.080],
  timeSec: [0.739, 0.067, 0.126, 0.435, 0.069, 0.646, 0.497, 0.068, 0.116, 0.135]
};

const testData = {
  sizeMB:  [5.000, 0.200, 0.001, 9.000, 0.002, 0.020, 0.008, 4.000, 0.001, 1.000],
  timeSec: [0.425, 0.098, 0.052, 0.686, 0.066, 0.078, 0.070, 0.375, 0.058, 0.136]
};

// Converting the data into tensor data type
const trainTensors = {
  sizeMB: tf.tensor2d(trainData.sizeMB, [10, 1]),
  timeSec: tf.tensor2d(trainData.timeSec, [10, 1])
};

const testTensors = {
  sizeMB: tf.tensor2d(testData.sizeMB, [10, 1]),
  timeSec: tf.tensor2d(testData.timeSec, [10, 1])
};


/**
A simple linear regression model which best suite the problem am trying to 
solve i.e determine download time [sec] for any given file size [MB]
*/

const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]})) // add layer (a single layer)

model.compile({loss: 'meanAbsoluteError', optimizer: 'sgd'}); // compile the model

// Train the model on the data set "this is show sample of existing data to the model so it can learn"
async function trainModel(){
    await model.fit(trainTensors.sizeMB, trainTensors.timeSec, {epochs: 20});
}

trainModel() // invoking the trainModel function

model.evaluate(testTensors.sizeMB, testTensors.timeSec); // evaluate the model with the test data

model.predict(tf.tensor1d([3.2])).print() // using the model to make prediction
```

**Answer Updated**:
The author of the question mentioned she/he/them is trying to "*predict house price using a few parameters like square, land square, number of rooms*"

This model won't change that much, the concept (the code above) is still more or less the same because this type of problem is a linear regression problem and it depends on you if you want it to be a multi-layer perceptron or single layer perceptron (for this I will make it multi-layer perceptron).

Things to note:

1. Normalize your data because your data (parameters or features) are not in the same range e.g `square [m2]: 54, 23, 19.5, 200, 75, 90`; `num_of_room: 4, 6, 2, 1, 10, 3`; `house_age [years]: 23, 10, 65, 7.5, 45, 32`.
   Normalizing the data to be in the same range will help prevent the model from being bias to parameters that has higher value. I won't delve deeply into detail of normalizing here but you can achieve this by finding the mean of the each parameter (dataMean) then subtract the mean from the data, finally divide the result by it standard deviation

```js
e.g how to normalize for house_age parameter
house_age = [23, 10, 65, 7.5, 45, 32]
hose_age_mean = 30.41 // Mean of the house age
house_age_std_dev = 20.03 // Standard deviation
house_age_normalize = [-0.3699451, -1.0189716, 1.7269096, -1.1437843, 0.7284074, 0.0793809]

// Normalize code will look like this (learn more [here][1])

data = tf.tensor1d([23, 10, 65, 7.5, 45, 32])

function determineMeanAndStddev(data) {
  const dataMean = data.mean(0);
  const diffFromMean = data.sub(dataMean);
  const squaredDiffFromMean = diffFromMean.square();
  const variance = squaredDiffFromMean.mean(0);
  const dataStd = variance.sqrt();
  console.log(dataMean, dataStd) 
  return {dataMean, dataStd}; // returns 30.41, 20.03
}

determineMeanAndStddev(data)

function normalizeTensor(data, dataMean, dataStd) {
  data.sub(dataMean).div(dataStd).print(); 
  return data.sub(dataMean).div(dataStd);
}

dataMean = tf.tensor1d([30.41])
dataStd = tf.tensor1d([20.03])

normalizeTensor(data, dataMean, dataStd) // returns [-0.3699451, -1.0189716, 1.7269096, -1.1437843, 0.7284074, 0.0793809]
```

2. Data Structure
   You can check the solution provided by Tensorflowjs team on Github (here: [data_link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/boston-housing/data.js)), the data that would be passed to the model would look something like this (if you have further question, feel free to ask):

```js
tensors: {
  trainFeatures,
  trainTarget,
  testFeatures,
  testTarget
}
```

**3. Model structure**

```js
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [housingData_numFeatures], // pass in number of parameters or features your are considering (house_age, square, num_of_room etc)
    units: 50,
    activation: 'sigmoid'
  }));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 50, activation: 'sigmoid'}));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));

model.summary();

model.compile({optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.01), loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

async function runModel(){
 await model.fit(tensors.trainFeatures, tensors.trainTarget, {
    batchSize: 50, 
    epochs: 300, // number of iteration
    validationSplit: 0.2, // percentage of the data to use to validate the model
 });

 const result = model.evaluate(tensors.testFeatures, tensors.testTarget, {batchSize: 50});

}
```

Here is a complete solution to a housing price prediction problem on Github by Tensorflowjs team ([Github solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/boston-housing)), you can look into it and modify it to your need.

Comment: I'm trying to predict house price using a few parameters like square, land square, number of rooms, etc. So it's not just x->y

Comment: I've modify the initial answer to answer your question. If you have further questions or clarification, feel free to ask.

In addition, here is a complete solution to a housing price prediction problem on Github by Tensorflowjs team (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/boston-housing), you can look into it and modify it to your need